# Rsync copies all files with executable permission

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, rsync, file-permissions

I ran the following command to back up my home-directory:

```
$ rsync -ahv \
      --info=progress2 \
      --partial \
      --exclude=.cache/ \
      --exclude=.miniconda3/ \
      --exclude=.thunderbird/ \
      --exclude=.vscode/ \
      --exclude=.cargo/ \
      /home/tim \
      /run/media/tim/Volume/Backups/Tim/2021-04-15/
```

However when the command was finished, I noticed, that all of my files have the executable flag set! For example when looking at my `Cheatsheets`-directory:

```
$ ls -l /home/tim/Cheatsheets/
total 3932
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim 2056316 11. Dez 14:43 comprehensive-latex-symbol-list.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  112655 16. Feb 2019  EmacsCheatsheet.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  186060  7. Jun 2019  GoogleColabShortcuts.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  217283 12. Dez 23:44 JupyterLabShortcuts.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim   28664  3. Mai 2019  JupyterNotebookCheatsheet.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim   82953 25. Jan 2019  LaTeX_Cheatsheet.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  261478 22. Sep 2018  LaTeXMathSymbols.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  574022 24. Okt 2018  LTspiceShortcuts.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim     634 24. Okt 2018  MagitWorkflow.org
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim   17754 24. Okt 2018  MagitWorkflow.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim   60448 24. Dez 2018  NeotreeCheatsheet.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  169752 18. Feb 2019  PCRE_Cheatsheet.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  146499 21. Mär 2019  VSCodeShortcuts.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim   79881  6. Nov 2018  WiresharkShortcuts.pdf
```

whereas in the backed up directory:

```
$ ls -l /run/media/tim/Volume/Backups/Tim/2021-04-15/tim/Cheatsheets/
total 5888
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim 2056316 11. Dez 14:43 comprehensive-latex-symbol-list.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  112655 16. Feb 2019  EmacsCheatsheet.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  186060  7. Jun 2019  GoogleColabShortcuts.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  217283 12. Dez 23:44 JupyterLabShortcuts.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim   28664  3. Mai 2019  JupyterNotebookCheatsheet.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim   82953 25. Jan 2019  LaTeX_Cheatsheet.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  261478 22. Sep 2018  LaTeXMathSymbols.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  574022 24. Okt 2018  LTspiceShortcuts.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim     634 24. Okt 2018  MagitWorkflow.org
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim   17754 24. Okt 2018  MagitWorkflow.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim   60448 24. Dez 2018  NeotreeCheatsheet.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  169752 18. Feb 2019  PCRE_Cheatsheet.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim  146499 21. Mär 2019  VSCodeShortcuts.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tim tim   79881  6. Nov 2018  WiresharkShortcuts.pdf
```

From `rsync`s manpage, I see that the flag `-a` which I've use is an alias to `-rlptgoD`, where `-p` should preserve the permissions. Where did I go wrong with this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a feature of `rsync`, it's a (missing) feature of your target file system.

My guess is that the target file system is an USB storage with NTFS or FAT file system. These file systems don't support changing the executable flag.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. I didn't think of that. The drive I use for backups is also used to save some things from a windows box. Apparently, Windows supports FAT, NTFS, exFAT, Live File System and ReFS. Is any of these filesystems supposed to work for my use-case of a cross-platform backup?

Comment: Would working with multiple partitions a better way? For example half NTFS for Win-backups; half ext4 for Linux-backups. Please excuse my (maybe trivial) questions, up until now, I could mostly push away having to deal with partitions and file-systems.

Comment: If you need correct permission, a separate partition is a good solution. But you have to decide on the size of the partitions in advance.